# In what sense the "pullback at $ x $" map if functorial?

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be differentiable manifolds, and let $ f\colon X\to Y $ be a smooth map.

Given $ x\in X $ one can define the canonical *pullback at $ x $* map
$$
f_x^*\colon \mathscr C_{Y,f(x)}^\infty\to \mathscr C_{X,x}^\infty
$$
between the stalks of the sheaf $ \mathscr C_Y^\infty $ of smooth functions on $ Y $ based at $ f(x) $, and the stalk of smooth functions on $ X $ based at $ x $. Recall that $ f_x^* $ maps a germ $ t_{f(x)} $ of representative $ (V,t) $ to the germ represented by $ (f^{-1}(V),t\circ f) $.

The map $ f_x^* $ has the following functorial-like properties:

1. $ (1_X)_x^* = 1_{\mathscr C_{X,x}^\infty} $;
2. $ (g\circ f)_x^* = f_x^*\circ g_{f(x)}^* $;

In particular this means that there exists a functor
$$
F\colon \mathrm{Diff(*)}^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Alg}_{\mathbb R}
$$
from the category of pointed manifolds to the category of algebras over the real numbers mapping $ (X,x) $ to the stalk $ \mathscr C_{X,x}^\infty $ and a smooth map $ f\colon (X,x)\to (Y,y) $ to $ f_x^*\colon \mathscr C_{Y,y}^\infty\to \mathscr C_{X,x}^\infty $.

Now, properties 1. and 2. can be easily checked by hand. Nevertheless am looking if there is a way to realize $ F $ as a composition of "known" functors.

P.S. I'm familiar with sheaf theory and with the theory of (locally) ringed spaces. $ F $ can be defined for those kind of spaces also, and I would be really happy to see an answer at that level of generality.

Comment: what do you mean with "known functors"? All the constructions in your post seem to be pretty well known.

Comment: I defined $ F $ "by hands" but then I thought that maybe $ F $ can be understood in a more structural way as a composition of "known"/"other"/"standard" functors.

Comment: Among other things writing $ F $ as the composite of functors-we-can-easily-check-that-they-are-functors would reduce amount of work require to check that $ F $ is a functor, at least in the case of (locally) ringed spaces where the functoriality condition 2. becomes quite messy.

Comment: Well, the stalk at a point is a colimit, and the map between stalks comes out of the universal property of colimits. Condition 2 should also follow easily from the "uniqueness" part of the universal property.

Comment: I guess you could phrase it geometrically for the category of pointed ringed spaces (ringed spaces with a map $x:1\to X$, where $1$ is a one point space) regarding the "stalk at $x$ operation" as the pullback sheaf along the map $x$  and the map between stalks is now a map of pullback sheaves over the singleton space. Does that work for you? or are you looking for something entirely different?

Comment: Yes, it kinda works.